# Toggle Icon on Button click React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, icons, toggle, react-component

I am trying to toggle the button icon when clicked in React app. I looked into the console, the value of "togglePassword" is changing on click but the button icon is not changing... How to correct this out?
Here is my code...

```
class Register extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            togglePassword: false
        };

        this.onToggle = this.onToggle.bind(this);
    }

    onToggle(e) {
      this.setState({ togglePassword: !this.state.togglePassword })
    }

    render() {
       return (
          <button onClick={this.onToggle} type="button">
             {
              this.state.togglePassword ? 
              <i className="fas fa-eye-slash"></i> : 
              <i className="fas fa-eye"></i>
             }
          </button>
       );
    }
}
```

The other method I tried is as below but the console gave me the following error when I clicked the button...

```
<button onClick={this.onToggle} type="button">
           {
            this.state.togglePassword &&
            (<i className="fas fa-eye-slash"></i>)
           }
           {
            !this.state.togglePassword &&
            (<i className="fas fa-eye"></i>)
           }        
</button>
```

Error: failed to execute "remove child" on "Node". The node to be removed is not a child of this node.

Comment: What do you mean by button icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be something else apart from the code you have provided,

Below code snippet, this is exact copy of your code, and its working fine :

---

```js
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            togglePassword: false
        };

        this.onToggle = this.onToggle.bind(this);
    }

    onToggle(e) {
      this.setState({ togglePassword: !this.state.togglePassword })
    }

    render() {
       return (
          <button onClick={this.onToggle} type="button">
             {
              this.state.togglePassword ? 
              "fa-eye-slash": 
              "fa-eye"
             }
          </button>
       );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```

**WORKING DEMO :** with font awesome

[image: Edit #SO-react-font-awesome]

Comment: I am not using a simple text for my button, which you have done. In case is we use a font-awesome icon, it's not working...

Comment: Any other methods and using font-awesome icon?

Comment: I still don't get it. My and your code are all same, what is the difference?? Can you please tell me what did you do?

Comment: I use font-awesome official CDN from their site, what did you do?

Comment: @Smile001, I just found demo online with font-awesome and put your code inside it, and its working,nothing else, you can create a demo same as you have in your local, then may be I can help you more

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 render() {
  const {togglePassword} = this.state
       return (
    <button onClick={this.onToggle} type="button">
           <i className={`fas fa-eye${togglePassword?"-slash:""}`}></i>
     </button>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seem to work for me with React Material MUI

```
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore';
import ExpandLessIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandLess';
```

...

```
const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };
```

...

```
<Button id="fade-button"onClick={handleClick}>
Text
{anchorEl ? <ExpandLessIcon /> : <ExpandMoreIcon />}
</Button>
```